# passing each element of array in the labels of char.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i am using chart.js i want to dynamically update label of my bar chart i have an array in javascript that takes it values from ajax now the issue is i want to pass each element of array in the label

```
   labels: [array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4]],
```

this is what am i doing i m hard-coding each element of array but this is not what i wanted i want to display each element of array dynamically.
I was thinking to take the length of array and then loop through the array till its length but again the issue is labels prop. of chart.js doesn't allow me to write JavaScript code in it....kindly help me

this is my code

```
         var label_values=$('.labels').text();
         //label_values has this string 
           "09:00:0010:00:0011:00:0012:00:0013:00:00"
         var array=[];
         array = label_values.match(/(\d+:){2}\d\d/g);
         var canavas=jQuery('<canvas id="myChart" style="width: 75%; display: block; border: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 70px; bottom: 0px";></canvas>');
         canavas.appendTo(overlay_body);
         var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
       var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
    labels: [array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4]],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Hourly Attendance',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max:60,
                min:0,
                step:10,
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }],


       }
   }
  });
      }// end 2nd ajx
    });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`labels` property accepts `array` so you can just pass the whole array

```
labels: array
```

Comment: i tried but it dint work it only displays the 1st element of array i.e array[0]

Comment: array=[09,10,11,12,13];

Comment: can u please make jsfiddle ?

Comment: i dont know how to use jsfiddle

Comment: Update your question with latest code where you have assigned `array` to labels

Comment: You are not using single array still you are assigning values one by one.

Comment: kindly tell me how should i ameliorate this cide

Comment: simply write this `labels: array,`